# C# WebBrowser - How to wait until DOM Element is loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have a WebBrowser element in my form.
It loads a page.
This is followed by code to wait until page is loaded:

```
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Then I make a sequence of GetElementByID.Focus statements.
Each of them is followed by command "SendKeys.Send("MyKeys")"
But when I run the program, web browser downloads needed a page, and all the "SendKeys" values appear to be typed in the last field.

Tried to pause it in many ways before filling in the fields, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("FirstName").SetAttribute("value", "John");
```

let me know how it goes.

Comment: Any specific reason why you have to use SendKeys? Probably there are other workaround available to accomplish the same thing.

As a side note, rather than using Application.DoEvents, I would have used ProgressChanged event to trap the ReadyState.